# How can I fix my Javascript slider button function which is being declared but its value is never read?

Tags: javascript, html, function, slider

I am making a HTML, CSS, Javascript slider with buttons on the bottom to indicate which slide is active. The dots should be passing back the value of 1,2,3 to the currentSlide function but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
//HTML
<div id="slider">
    <div class="slide active">
         <p>slide1</p>
    </div>

    <div class="slide">
         <p>slide2</p>
    </div>

    <div class="slide">
         <p>slide3</p>
    </div>

    <div>
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
    </div>
</div>

//CSS


//Javascript
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slide");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

Any feedback will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You were never setting `slideIndex` to `n` when it was actually a valid value - see the changes below in the snippet.

```js
//Javascript
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slide");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");

  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  else if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  else { slideIndex = n }
  
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }

  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

```html
<div id="slider">
    <div class="slide active">
         <p>slide1</p>
    </div>

    <div class="slide">
         <p>slide2</p>
    </div>

    <div class="slide">
         <p>slide3</p>
    </div>

    <div>
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)">1</span>
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)">2</span>
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)">3</span>
    </div>
</div>
```